# How can I decode HTML characters in C#?

Tags: c#

I have email addresses encoded with HTML character entities. Is there anything in .NET that can convert them to plain strings?

Answer (score 677, accepted):

You can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode).

If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode) which does not require an extra assembly reference as it is available in the `System.Net` namespace.

Comment: Add a reference to System.Web.Dll in your project properties.  The classes you see live in System.dll which is referenced by default.

Comment: In case you're trying trying to decode the Query String, you need to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

Comment: does not decode &#233;  none of the answers do. HtmlUtility/WebUtility cannot do this.

Answer (score 205):

On .Net 4.0:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

No need to include assembly for a C# project

Comment: It is better solution because HttpUtility doesn't decode "&apos;" symbol.. I don't know why..

Comment: This is required in developing for the Universal Windows platform.

Comment: Will this cause XSS in .Net web pages?

Answer (score 46):

As @CQ says, you need to use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx), but it's not available in a non-ASP .NET project by default.

For a non-ASP .NET application, you need to add a reference to `System.Web.dll`.  Right-click your project in Solution Explorer, select "Add Reference", then browse the list for `System.Web.dll`.

Now that the reference is added, you should be able to access the method using the fully-qualified name `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` or insert a `using` statement for `System.Web` to make things easier.

Answer (score 16):

If there is no Server context (i.e your running offline), you can use [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx).[HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx).

Comment: Agreed, that's why I use HttpUtility, fell into same trap =P

Answer (score 16):

To decode HTML take a look below code

```
string s = "Svendborg V&#230;rft A/S";
string a = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
Response.Write(a);
```

Output is like

```
 Svendborg Værft A/S
```

Comment: The 'ToString()' is redundant since HtmlDecode returns a string

Answer (score 12):

It is also worth mentioning that if you're using HtmlAgilityPack like I was, you should use `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize()`. It takes a `string` and returns a `string`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Server.HtmlDecode` to decode the HTML entities. If you want to *escape* the HTML, i.e. display the `<` and `>` character to the user, use `Server.HtmlEncode`.

Comment: There may not be a server context (i.e. when running test cases and the like) I fell in to this trap before :)

Answer (score 1):

Write static a method into some utility class, which accept string as parameter and return the decoded html string.

Include the `using System.Web.HttpUtility` into your class

```
public static string HtmlEncode(string text)
    {
        if(text.length > 0){

           return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
        }else{

         return text;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For .net **4.0**

Add a reference to `System.net.dll` to the project with `using System.Net;` then use the following extensions

```
// Html encode/decode
    public static string HtmDecode(this string htmlEncodedString)
    {
        if(htmlEncodedString.Length > 0)
        {
            return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlEncodedString);
        }
        else
        {
            return htmlEncodedString;
        }
    }

    public static string HtmEncode(this string htmlDecodedString)
    {
        if(htmlDecodedString.Length > 0)
        {
            return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlDecodedString);
        }
        else
        {
            return htmlDecodedString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For strings containing &#x20; I've had to double-decode the string.  First decode would turn it into   the second pass would correctly decode it to the expected character.