# How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex, string

Using ASP.NET, how can I strip the HTML tags from a given string reliably (i.e. not using regex)? I am looking for something like PHP's `strip_tags`.

#### Example:

`<ul><li>Hello</li></ul>`

#### Output:

"Hello"

I am trying not to reinvent the wheel, but I have not found anything that meets my needs so far.

Comment: I would imagine that PHP strip_tags uses regex behind the scenes!

Comment: @Daniel: because regex is very bad at that, especially if you have nesting.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like PHP's Strip_Tags is particularly reliable either going on the offical notes and the comments: http://uk.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove all HTML tags from a string without knowing which tags are in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If it is just stripping *all* HTML tags from a string, this works <s>reliably</s> with regex as well. Replace:

```
<[^>]*(>|$)
```

with the empty string, globally. Don't forget to normalize the string afterwards, replacing:

```
[\s\r\n]+
```

with a single space, and trimming the result. Optionally replace any HTML character entities back to the actual characters.

**Note**:

1. There is a limitation: HTML and XML allow `>` in attribute values. This solution *will* return broken markup when encountering such values.
2. The solution is technically safe, as in: The result will never contain anything that could be used to do cross site scripting or to break a page layout. It is just not very clean.
3. As with all things HTML and regex:
   **Use [a proper parser](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) if you must get it right under all circumstances.**

Comment: Although not requested, I think a lot of readers will want to also strip HTM-encoding, like `&quote;`. I combine it with [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c) for that (which in turn will not remove tags). Use it after tag-removal, since it may rewrite `&gt;` and `&lt;`. E.g. `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(myTextVariable, "<[^>]*(>|$)", string.Empty))`

Comment: @YahooSerious Thank you for providing an example. This works great. Thank you.

Comment: Html Agility Pack is the way to go, I used it way back in webforms to strip entire web pages to use content!

Comment: Totally a newbie at this. how would I implement the above webUtility.HtmlDecode code into my source. I am using CkEditor

Comment: @YahooSerious this will allow a XSS vector in however
&gt; script &lt; alert("XXS"); &gt; / script &lt;
Will not be sanitized by the regex but converted by HtmlDecode to 
<script>alert("XXS");</ script>

Comment: @Heather Very good point. HTML tag stripping would have to be done again after entity decoding.

Answer (score 78):

Go download HTMLAgilityPack, now! ;)  [Download LInk](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

This allows you to load and parse HTML.  Then you can navigate the DOM and extract the inner values of all attributes.  Seriously, it will take you about 10 lines of code at the maximum.  It is one of the greatest free .net libraries out there.

Here is a sample:

```
            string htmlContents = new System.IO.StreamReader(resultsStream,Encoding.UTF8,true).ReadToEnd();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(htmlContents);
            if (doc == null) return null;

            string output = "";
            foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                output += node.InnerText;
            }
```

Comment: you can even query every `text()` node, trim the contents and string.Join those with space. `IEnumerable<string> allText = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()").Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim())`

Comment: or simply use doc.DocumentNode.InnerText, though this has some issues with whitespacehandling it seems...

Comment: Why the `if (doc == null)` check?  This is always false, not so?

Answer (score 70):

```
Regex.Replace(htmlText, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Has many issues - doesn't deal with attributes having < or > in them and doesn't do well with tags that span more than one line unless run with `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.

Comment: Noooo, use "<[^>]*>".

Answer (score 11):

```
protected string StripHtml(string Txt)
{
    return Regex.Replace(Txt, "<(.|\\n)*?>", string.Empty);
}    

Protected Function StripHtml(Txt as String) as String
    Return Regex.Replace(Txt, "<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty)
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't work for lots of cases including non-unix linebreaks.

Answer (score 6):

I've posted this on the asp.net forums, and it still seems to be one of the easiest solutions out there. I won't guarantee it's the fastest or most efficient, but it's pretty reliable. 
In .NET you can use the HTML Web Control objects themselves. All you really need to do is insert your string into a temporary HTML object such as a DIV, then use the built-in 'InnerText' to grab all text that is not contained within tags. See below for a simple C# example:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
htmlDiv.InnerHtml = htmlString;
String plainText = htmlDiv.InnerText;
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, I tested it with simple InnerHtml="<b>foo</b>"; and InnerText has value "<b>foo</b>" :(

Comment: Don't do this. This solution injects un-encoded html directly into the output. This would leave you wide open to Cross Site Scripting attacks - you have just allowed anyone that can change the html string to inject any arbitrary html and javascript into your application!

Answer (score 5):

I have written a pretty fast method in c# which beats the hell out of the Regex. It is hosted in [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MCMS/htmlTagStripper.aspx) on CodeProject.

Its advantages are, among better performance the ability to replace named and numbered HTML entities (those like `&amp;amp;` and `&203;`) and comment blocks replacement and more.

Please read the [related article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MCMS/htmlTagStripper.aspx).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who can't use the HtmlAgilityPack, .NETs XML reader is an option. This can fail on well formatted HTML though so always add a catch with regx as a backup. Note this is NOT fast, but it does provide a nice opportunity for old school step through debugging.

```
public static string RemoveHTMLTags(string content)
    {
        var cleaned = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder textOnly = new StringBuilder();
            using (var reader = XmlNodeReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader("<xml>" + content + "</xml>")))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                        textOnly.Append(reader.ReadContentAsString());
                }
            }
            cleaned = textOnly.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            //A tag is probably not closed. fallback to regex string clean.
            string textOnly = string.Empty;
            Regex tagRemove = new Regex(@"<[^>]*(>|$)");
            Regex compressSpaces = new Regex(@"[\s\r\n]+");
            textOnly = tagRemove.Replace(content, string.Empty);
            textOnly = compressSpaces.Replace(textOnly, " ");
            cleaned = textOnly;
        }

        return cleaned;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(anytext, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at the Regex based solutions suggested here, and they don't fill me with any confidence except in the most trivial cases. An angle bracket in an attribute is all it would take to break, let alone mal-formmed HTML from the wild. And what about entities like `&amp;`? If you want to convert HTML into plain text, you need to decode entities too.

So I propose the method below.

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack), this extension method efficiently strips all HTML tags from an html fragment. Also decodes HTML entities like `&amp;`. Returns just the inner text items, with a new line between each text item.

```
public static string RemoveHtmlTags(this string html)
{
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            return html;

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        if (doc.DocumentNode == null || doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes == null)
        {
            return WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var i = 0;

        foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            var text = node.InnerText.SafeTrim();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                sb.Append(text);

                if (i < doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            i++;
        }

        var result = sb.ToString();

        return WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
}

public static string SafeTrim(this string str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return null;

    return str.Trim();
}
```

If you are really serious, you'd want to ignore the contents of certain HTML tags too (`<script>`, `<style>`, `<svg>`, `<head>`, `<object>` come to mind!) because they probably don't contain readable content in the sense we are after. What you do there will depend on your circumstances and how far you want to go, but using HtmlAgilityPack it would be pretty trivial to whitelist or blacklist selected tags.

If you are rendering the content back to an HTML page, make sure you understand XSS vulnerability & [how to prevent it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F) - i.e. always encode any user-entered text that gets rendered back onto an HTML page (`>` becomes `&gt;` etc).

Answer (score 1):

For those who are complining about Michael Tiptop's solution not working, here is the .Net4+ way of doing it:

```
public static string StripTags(this string markup)
{
    try
    {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(markup);
        XPathDocument doc;
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr,
                           new XmlReaderSettings()
                           {
                               ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
                               // for multiple roots
                           }))
        {
            doc = new XPathDocument(xr);
        }

        return doc.CreateNavigator().Value; // .Value is similar to .InnerText of  
                                           //  XmlDocument or JavaScript's innerText
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string str = Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HTMLString), "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) which is an alternative to HtmlAgilityPack (not that HAP is bad).  It is easier to use than HAP to get the text out of a HTML source.

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var htmlDocument = parser.ParseDocument(source);
var text = htmlDocument.Body.Text();
```

You can take a look at the [key features](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp#key-features) section where they make a case at being "better" than HAP.  I think for the most part, it is probably overkill for the current question but still, it is an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For the second parameter,i.e. keep some tags, you may need some code like this by using HTMLagilityPack:

```
public string StripTags(HtmlNode documentNode, IList keepTags)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var childNode in documentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.Name.ToLower() == "#text")
            {
                result.Append(childNode.InnerText);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!keepTags.Contains(childNode.Name.ToLower()))
                {
                    result.Append(StripTags(childNode, keepTags));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Append(childNode.OuterHtml.Replace(childNode.InnerHtml, StripTags(childNode, keepTags)));
                }
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

More explanation on this page: http://nalgorithm.com/2015/11/20/strip-html-tags-of-an-html-in-c-strip_html-php-equivalent/

Answer (score -5):

Simply use `string.StripHTML();`

Comment: As @Serpiton points out, there isn't such a method in the BCL. Could you point to an implementation of this method or provide your own?