# Get a subsection of HTML document

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to get a subsection of an HTML page. The functionality I am looking for is similar to the one implemented on most blogs. Usually, on the main page of the blog, you only see a section of the post, and when you click on the title you get the full content of that blog post.
There must be code that exists to get that subsection without breaking the HTML.

Does anyone know of good .NET code that does that?

EDIT: I need to keep the HTML formatting of the content, so stripping all the HTML isn't really an option. I wouldn't mind taking a fixed-length substring of the content (i.e. the first 800 characters or so) but then not breaking the HTML would be a nightmare.

Thanks!

Comment: is your datasource the html page? or do you have a database with the entries in it?

Comment: My datasource is a database with an entry in it, so I start with a String that contains all the content of my post. This is SharePoint, so the content is stored in a field of my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strip the html first from the content string ([How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/asp-net-strip-html-tags)) then do a `left` on the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this works by taking a substring of the contents of that blog post before the blog post is rendered into html.

Comment: But then you would lose all the HTML from your post (links, tables, etc.)?

Comment: You need to strip out the html tags from your post - Daniels answer links to a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't be done by cutting the page output directly (messing with the HTML).

Handle that with server-side code displaying a trim of the blog content.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way that's done isn't by chunking off a piece of the HTML. Rather, There's a database that contains the blog posts, and the Main page has it's own HTML/CSS which dynamically loads only the first X paragraphs of each blog post.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind the "simplest thing that could possibly work" would be to scan the blog post that you want to summarize until you get to the first close-paragraph `</p>` tag.

Don't be tempted to [scan the HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).