# Text Editor - Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a text editor for my asp.net mvc project. I was able to find a lot of text editor out there works pretty well.

What I am looking for is a editor that accept only regualr character like "I am a superman".
I do not want to save "`<p><strong>I am a superman</strong></p>`" into my SQL table since I have to show it thru textbox(example : `<%= Html.TextBox("Remark", Model.empExperience.Remark)%>`).

Let me know.

Comment: This is what I did.                                                 public string StripTags(string strHTML)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strHTML))
               return string.Empty;

           // Removes tags from passed HTML           
           strHTML = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(strHTML);
           strHTML = Regex.Replace(strHTML, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);

           return strHTML;
       }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you do not wish to allow HTML, your best bet is to simply have a means of stripping HTML from the provided input. There's no need to implement a custom text editor for this sort of thing.

Have a look at: [How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/asp-net-strip-html-tags/785743#785743)

Comment: Your answer sounds right, but it looks complicate to use "<[^>]*>". Let's say there is a HTML string "&lt;p&gt;I worked.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;". How do you convert it to "I worked" by using "<[^>]*>"? I tried with many sample code from the link that you provided, but I could not make it work.

Comment: If that's your string, you would have to decode it first, e.g. HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myHtmlEncodedString) before using the RegEx

Comment: I did HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myHtmlEncodedString) and I also Iadded Regex.Replace(myHtmlEncodedString, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty). It worked out. Thanks Nathan and JustineStolle

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it (to sum up the answers on the link Nathan provided):

```
    private static readonly Regex StripHtml = new Regex("<[^>]*>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Strips all HTML tags from the specified string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "html">The string containing HTML</param>
    /// <returns>A string without HTML tags</returns>
    public static string StripHtmlTags(string html)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            return string.Empty;

        return StripHtml.Replace(html, string.Empty);
    }
```