# Plain text from database

Tags: asp.net

I have used ckeditor  in my application which enables the user to store the data in db in form of tags like 
br>

bold
i> 
etc but i want the data to be populated in the datagrid should be a plain text irrespective of any styles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.NET - Strip HTML Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/asp-net-strip-html-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Html to Text Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/HTML_to_Plain_Text.aspx), but if you need to display plain text then why allow user to add html content.

Below is also a way to do this:-

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
htmlDiv.InnerHtml = htmlString;
String plainText = htmlDiv.InnerText;
```