# Remove anchor tag from Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How to remove the anchor tag from a string, I have a large text in that some word have anchor tag I want to remove that anchor tag and want to show plain word(with out anchor tag). My text is look like:

> [LoremIpsum.Net](http://test.com) is a small and simple static site that
>   [provides](http://test123.com) you with a decent sized passage without having to use a
>   generator. The site also provides an all caps version of the text, as
>   well as translations, and an [explanation](http://test445.com) of what this famous.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a **very** simple (and non-bullet proof) example, see below. I must still strongly advise that you find a "proper" html parser, however.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                String sample = "<a href=\"http://test.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">LoremIpsum.Net</a> is a small and simple static site that <a href=\"http://test123.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">provides</a> you with a decent sized passage without having to use a generator. The site also provides an all caps version of the text, as well as translations, and an <a href=\"http://test445.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">explanation</a> of what this famous.";

                String re = @"<a [^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>";
                Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sample, re, "$1"));
        }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> LoremIpsum.Net is a small and simple static site that provides you with a decent sized passage without having to use a generator. The site also provides an all caps version of the text, as well as translations, and an explanation of what this famous.

Comment: what I need to do if I just want to remove only some selected anchor tag?, like if I want to remove the anchor tag of "provides".

Comment: @askiitians: If you know the text within the anchor, replace the `(.*?)` in the **re** string with that text, then replace the `"$1"` in the Replace call again with that text.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code to strip Html:

```
public static string StripHTML(this string HTMLText)
{
    var reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.Replace(HTMLText, "").Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
}
```

Comment: what I need to do if I just want to remove only some selected anchor tag?, like if I want to remove the anchor tag of "provides".

Comment: Then you should check out the HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 0):

Nice example here :

http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags