# how to search html content?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

in my website user can add HTML content with WYSIWYG control . and i save these content to database .
i want to have a search  on these data so i use this query :

```
select * from htmlcontent where content like '%' + @searchValue + '%'
```

but for example when user search `"<p>"` this query return all rows in my table . but i want user only can search on the html content (**data that user can seen on the browser**  ) not tags

how can i do it ?

**Edited :** 
**i want user search html content not tags . some thing like search in the browser(ctrl + F)**

Comment: Depending on what the HTML is, the user could see almost anything.  There could be an iFrame for GoogleCalendar, literally anything.  So you need a clearer definition of "data that user can seen on the browser".  Your best bet may be that the WYSIWYG control is able to save the html output as text only - Then store both the text only and the html.  Then you can search the "text only" field.  But don't expect SQL to parse HTML for you, it's not relly it's job, do that outside of the database ;)

Comment: so i have to duplicate data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all the HTML tags from the users input string, then search using the cleaned string. You might want to replace all found tags with `%` in order to match when tags are found within the content. For information on how to remove tag from the input string, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

Another alternative is to clean the WYSIWYG string, then search that. Neither of these two can be performed in the database without major string trickery. You are better off solving this on the ASP side.

Comment: As far as I understand, he's searching for HTML elements. If he removes it there's no way to look for them.

Comment: No, he wants the user to **not** get results when the user searches using tags. He only wants to search for the data between the tags

Comment: He's searching for `<p>` which is an HTML tag, but the result should be what's inside. If you remove tags how can you know what's inside them? You're saying remove tags and then search, I think it's search and then remove tags.

Comment: He is searching for `<p>` which returns the full table. Which is not what he wants. Your solution will still return the full table if you search for `<p>`, only with the beginning and end tags stripped from the result. The question is unclear enough that it's hard to tell what the asker really wants though :)

Comment: There are several options in the linked question, a simple solution is `searchValue = Regex.Replace(searchValue, "<.*?>", string.Empty);`. As I said, you might want to replace `string.Empty` with `%` to get results where a tag is in the center of the text.

Comment: If you write a naive html filter, then you have to be careful of unintended consequences.  Tables of data becoming concatenated string `<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr><tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>` => `abcd` with no delimiters.  Using an html parser to generate text only output would at least give spaces between the items, maybe drawing an ascii table around it.  Whatever solution you go for, be aware of all the consequences, and never assume quick/simple to always be the best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can use `TrimStart('<p>')` and `TrimEnd('</p>')` on the results to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify the seach string on the way in so that it strips html tags there. Then check that the string is not empty before your search.

So a search string like <p>Hello</p> becomes just Hello