# How to extract C#/PHP/Code/SQL from string in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, parsing, sql-injection

Let suppose there is file-upload control which allow user to upload text file how can we read or extract that user has not upload any malicious code in that text file..

Comment: Can you also expand on this use case? Are you executing text files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not executing these files, the only thing you may need is excluding html tags [How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Removing them may not be needed - encoding them may be enough.