# Avoid splitting of HTML tags in string

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom made news page in my website.  The problem is adding a "more" option if the string returned from the database exceeds 400 characters.  Splitting the string after 400 characters may sometimes mean that an HTML tag might be split in half, or text contained within the html tag will be split, not giving the right look when splitted.

Is there anyway I can possibly avoid this, or am I going at this all wrong?

I am currently using the Literal Control to display the string, and if the string.length > 400 I use the substring method to obtain the first 400 characters for display.
If the "more" option is clicked, I will display the full string.

Comment: Do you really need to keep the html tags in the summary?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is how I retrieve it from the Database, as a user can add articles to it through an html text editor.  But do you have any other suggestions as to how not to make it part of the summary?

Comment: I suggest to remove the html tags

Answer (score 1):

What would I do is to strip the HTML tags from the content and then truncate it to 400 characters.

```
strContent = Regex.Replace(strContent, "<.*?>", "")

If strContent.Length > 400 Then
   strContent = strContent.Substring(0, 400)
   btnMore.Visibile = True
Else
   btnMore.Visibile = False
End If
```

Comment: I think that should be `strContent.Substring(0, 400)`. `SubString` is zero-indexed

Answer (score 0):

Strip out the HTML content from your summary string before truncating to 400 characters.

This is the neatest way you can display a short summary, and will prevent any issues with tags left open.

---

For info on how to strip, see this SO Post:

[How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

```
Regex.Replace(htmlText, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```