# How to convert html text to raw text in code behind in other words strip text from html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using a rss feed(syndicationfeed) I have some encoded text where normally in the view I can just say @Html.Raw(feed.summary) where feed.summary is some html with text in it, and it will display the text without all the html code. However for some reason, this is not working. It's breaking my view, no crashing its just not displaying anything. So I was wondering if there is a way to do this in code behind that way the text will all ready be stipped and I don't have to use Html.Raw() in my view. Any advice is appreciated.

```
 @Html.Raw(feed.RssShortSummary) 
  //This doesn't work, it messes all my styling up and simply doesn't even display the text.
```

In Code behind: (I've tried MvcHtmlString.Create()) but still returns the html code and not the text I need from it.

```
   MvcHtmlString.Create(summary);
```

So if I have:

```
 <p>Here is some text</p>
```

Html.Raw() will return "Here is some text" but this messes my view for some reason. I've tried MvcHtmlString.Create but it is still returning to me:

```
<p>Here is some text</p> //returning all the html instead just "Here is some text"
```

In code c# I tried:

```
  var x = MvcHtmlString.Create(rssItem.RssSummary);
```

where for example rssItem.RssSummary =

```
  <p>Here is some text</p>
```

x is still generating:

```
     <p>Here is some text</p>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please show us more code.

Comment: What do you see in the generated source?

Comment: Ok I added to show what is being generated. Instead of giving me the description(text) summary of the rss feed it returning all the html where it's located.

Comment: I still don't get it. So you basically want to strip the HTML markup from a string? Then its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net

Comment: Why use regex? That is what that supposedly duplicate is saying to use. Wouldn't, shouldn't Html.Raw(//Html tag content) do the same thing which is a lot easier than regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches for removing tags in .net, [C# Remove HTML Tags](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags) nice article in which described several approaches for removing tags, based on that article, the best approach to remove tags is StripTagsCharArray because it more faster than Regex approaches:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML tags from string using char array.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
    {
    char[] array = new char[source.Length];
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    bool inside = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        char let = source[i];
        if (let == '<')
        {
        inside = true;
        continue;
        }
        if (let == '>')
        {
        inside = false;
        continue;
        }
        if (!inside)
        {
        array[arrayIndex] = let;
        arrayIndex++;
        }
    }
    return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }
```