# how to get the text content of html

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

How to get the text content of html in asp.net?

I wrote the following code in asp.net  but it gave me the html not text?

code are here :

```
Function GetData(ByVal dta As String)

        Dim comp As New Literal
        comp.Text = dta
            Return comp.Text
End Function
```

For example :

input :   `<span><p>  this is html </p></span>`

output should be :  this is html

Comment: Do you want the content of the asp page that is executing or external html page?

Comment: This is really unclear. What input do you give the method, what output do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Don't think the `comp` is doing much, all you do is copy the string, and then return that result, so effectively, you're returning `dta`. So this is basically nothing more than an identity function. What are you trying to do, and what is not working?

Comment: the question is clear i need text content from the html for example <p>hi all</p>  i need to return hi all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Function GetData(ByVal dta As String)

        Return Regex.Replace(dta, "<[^>]*(>|$)", String.Empty)
    End Function
```