# Fetching content of multiline textbox using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

```
TextBox txtContent = new TextBox();

SPList announcementList = mySite.Lists["Announcements"];
SPListItem getAnnouncement = announcementList.Items[0];
txtContent.Text = getAnnouncement["Body"].ToString();
```

this gives output as

```
<div class="ExternalClass61EB4AB2F639401D9141EADFC30FEDFE">
    <p>Please follow plan of action.​</p>
</div>
```

I want output as

```
"Please follow plan of action."
```

Please Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SPFieldMultiLineText` like the following:

```
SPListItem getAnnouncement = announcementList.Items[0];
SPFieldMultiLineText bodyField = getAnnouncement.Fields.GetField("Body") as SPFieldMultiLineText;
string txt = bodyField.GetFieldValueAsText(getAnnouncement["Body"]);
string html = bodyField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(getAnnouncement["Body"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove the HTML from the content, this answer will help you:

[How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

There are a number of solutions there, such as the one with Regex. You would just need this line of code:

```
txtContent.Text=WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(getAnnouncement["Body"].ToString(), "<[^>]*(>|$)", string.Empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText(text, text.Length - 1);
```