# C# with HTML Tags

Tags: c#, html, string, html-parsing

I have a website that will read in particular XML style file with PHP and display some content. The people updating the website aren't so techincally minded and so I was hoping to create a program coverting a Powerpoint into the type of XML I'm looking for.

I convert the PowerPoint -> RTF -> HTML. A sample output is below:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri font-size:44pt;">Title 1</span></p>
<p><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;font-size:32pt;">Data in here.</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;font-size:32pt;">More Data.</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I wish to read this HTMl line-by-line, interpreting tags and creating my own file out of the data.

**I.e:** Every tag with a particular tag will be classed as a title, then anything with another particular tag will be classed as data.

Example Ouptut:

```
<FILE>
    <ITEM>
        <TITLE>Title 1</TITLE>
        <DATA><p>Data in here</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>More Data.</p></DATA>
    </ITEM>
</FILE>
```

(How) can this be done?

Note: ***I am not looking for how to remove all tags: [Like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net) and [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)***

Note2: ***The Powerpoint does not have a fixed font/font-size. If possible, I'd like it to be completely sytle independant. If this would not work, could it be done with a fixed template in PowerPoint so every title and data section would be the same, thus having the same tags?***

Comment: You can use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) plugin like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)? That is what they are meant for: "non technical" people. They are really easy to implement, and all you would need to do to save to your XML would be getting a string out of a textarea element. I don't know your project or if you have other reasons for using PowerPoint, but I just think it would take you a huge effort to come up with something better than these plugins out of a PPT.

Comment: This is good, but not exaclty what I'm looking for. my program will run client side, before uploading to server.

Comment: And why would that be a issue?

Comment: Is there a way to get the data form the textarea, via C# or without the use of PHP running on the client?

Comment: Assuming your program runs on a browser, as you said it is a website, you can manipulate it on the client using javascript. How would it work with the PPT? Another thing that I don't get is why do you need c# AND php.