# How to get only text from html content inside of a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDb())
{
   var post = context.Posts.Where(p => p.ThreadId == item).OrderBy(p => p.DateCreated).First();
   ViewBag.Description = post.Conent; //post.Content contains content of the post; that means html + user text
}
```

Currently my `ViewBag.Description` contains everything that is inside of `post.Content`, and I need it to contain only text. How do I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Use Regex To remove html tags

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to remove HTML tags from a string:

```
public string StripHtml(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, "<(.|\\n)*?>", string.Empty);
}
```