# how to remove an tag attribute

Tags: c#, html, tags

I have a table that has a summary tag that I want to remove

```
<table summary="Summary">...
```

I need to remove the summary tag and I can't use jquery. I need to remove it from the page source.

Is this possible with c#?

Comment: Use `HtmlAgilityPack`. If it's `ASP.NET` or another serverside-technology you should clarify your requirement.

Comment: You want to remove `summary` attribute or `table` tag which has summary attribute? Also it's not clear what you mean by page source - is it HTML string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Tim - using c# in asp.net. Sergey - I just want to remove the summary attribute and not the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").removeAttribute("summary");
```

or with C#:

```
<table runat="server" id="myTable" summary="Summary">...
(mark-up)

myTable.Attributes.Remove("summary");
(C#)
```

Note, the above assumes you're working in asp. net.

Comment: _"or with C#:"_ This is a method from ASP.NET, you should mention it since `ASP.NET` is _not_ tagged.

Comment: Thanks - I can see that it removes the summary attribute in the dom - but it still exists in the page source. Is there anyway to remove it from page source too?

Comment: Which method have you chosen? Be aware that sometimes when you 'view source' in a browser, it makes a fresh request for the page. It's not necessarily the same DOM you can see in the browser. Instead, inspect element and see if it's still there.