# How to remove all HTML formatting from string

Tags: c#, php, html

I'm currently querying a php script from C# in a WinForms app using the WebClient class.

The php script returns errors formatted in html as they are designed to be displayed in a webpage.

Example:

```
<br />
<b>Error:</b> Undefined value xyz in /var/www/sdsd/sdsd/asdsd.php
<br />
```

The response code may be more complex containg other HTML types.

Is there anything I can do to allow .NET to interpret the HTML and return to me the values that the user would expect to see. 
So ideally I would want to receive `"Error: Undefined value xyz in /var/www/sdsd/sdsd/asdsd.php"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
 htmlinput =
 "<br /> <b>Error:</b> Undefined value xyz in /var/www/sdsd/sdsd/asdsd.php <br />"

 nonhtmloutput =
 Regex.Replace(htmlinput,@"\<.*?\>", String.Empty)
```

A simple regex to clear anything in <> brackets and the brackets themselves

Comment: Ill give you the answer because its the easiest. Also note you need to put an @ symbol before your regex string for it to compile. Regex.Replace(htmlinput, @"\<.*?\>", String.Empty)

Comment: @cathalmf sure thing I edited my answer, I am programming Visual Basic right now, thats why the mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this, a quick google returns [stackoverflow - strip html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net) and [dotnetperls - remove html tags](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags) which I think satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

the reason your C# script brings back html tags is because when it reads the php tags and gets the strings from the page, it does not decode it from html.

all you do is add this to your hmtl string in your c# script

```
string StringFromPHPPage = StringFromPHPPage.server.htmldecode();
//that decodes the html tags.
```

Comment: What namespace are you getting that from?

Comment: "web" under the "systems" namespace

Comment: @cathalMF thats not what you want it comes from HttpServerUtility  but HTML encoding only makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>), the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing bracket of an HTML tag.
When the characters are HTML encoded, they are converted to the strings &lt; and &gt;, which causes the browser to display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

Comment: Then im not understanding, are you trying to display text from your webpage. Is it this displayed on the webpage or on the app?