# How to remove html tag of meta tag in view MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

I have meta tag and it contain html tag. I want to remove this.
Example content as :

`<p><b>This is red color</b><br>`

This is snipped code in view MVC

`<meta name="description" content="@Model.description" />`

Parameter `@Model.description` contain content text.

Comment: Are you looking to just strip the html tags? Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/785715/728795)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **regex** to replace your html tags. For example,

```
string myContent = Regex.Replace(description, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Or-else you can use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx) for .Net 4.0+ and for older version 
[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx).

Hope it helps :)