# Post HTML message to Facebook Page from ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, facebook, richtextbox

I would like to send a message to facebook page from my `asp.net` website.
I done it successfully but the problem is that when I changed the textbox to richtextbox the text is in the HTML format. 
The question is how to send the actual text to facebook?

I mean instead of sending the following text:

```
<strong> this text is bold </strong>
```

I want to send:

**this text is bold**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t send bold text in a message. Just strip the HTML tags before sending. How to do that is explained here, for example: [How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: strip the text will just remove the HTML tags. If it is that way I would just return to a simple textbox.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to send some format to the text

Comment: ...which is impossible, i´m afraid. you cannot even do that on facebook.com (or in the messenger).

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that