# Html code removal error while loop c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a small piece of software that takes the HTML data from a specific website(The SCP foundation to be precise) and I am having trouble removing the html code (`<html> <br>` etc...). I need to remove the html so it doesnt show up in the final string(newDescri) but everytime i call this function, it freezes my windows form. Thanks in advance!

```
void HTMLrem()
        {    
            while (htmlf)
            {    
                string text = data;    
                htmlcode = getBetween(text, "<", ">");

                if (htmlcode != "")
                {    
                    newDescri = newDescri.Replace("<" + htmlcode + ">", "");
                }
                else
                {    
                    htmlf = false;
                }
            }    
        }
```

edit: so sorry, i forgot to paste the code the first time *facepalm*

Comment: I'm sure you realize we can't see your screen or magically see what is in your mind right? Please post some code!

Comment: You can download the webpage and then get all the text (code) to a string. Then remove all the words that start with '<' character using regex. If need a more accurate answer, pls add some code or image. Otherwise, you are getting a lot of negative marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, as was said, you should show some code and be specific.  If you're aiming for just removing HTML from a string, then the following answer may help:

[How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

If you're having the form itself freeze, one way you can deal with determining what's causing it is by setting a breakpoint early on, and gradually step to the section that's causing the problem.  You can get it down to the method/call that's doing it.