# How to capitalize words in a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a string say "my name is john". Now I want to convert this string to "My Name Is John". how would I do that? I am using C# language. I am new to C# and don't have much idea on string manipulation.

I have tried this code

```
string functionName = "my name is john";
var dam = Char.ToUpperInvariant(functionName[0]) + functionName.Substring(1);
```

the output is "My name is john".
I want "My Name Is John".

Comment: you'll need to show what you've attempted and explain exactly what didn't work when you tried this.

Comment: I have added some codes as well. it will be great if anyone can help me.

Comment: [How to capitalize the first character of each word, or the first character of a whole string, with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913090/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-or-the-first-character-of-a)

Answer (score 0):

use this :

> ```
>     string UpperFirstWords(string input)
>     {
>         string[] list = input.Split(' ');
>         string[] output=list.Select(x => x = x[0].ToString().ToUpper() + x.Substring(1)).ToArray<string>();
>         return string.Join(" ", output);
>     }
> ```

```
        string mystr = "my name is john";
        string outp = UpperFirstWords(mystr);
```

after running , the outp value is : My Name Is John