# Encoding string C#

Tags: c#

I get a page response from a web and it is having strings like `"Lluís Quílez"`. But i get it as `"Llu&#xED;s Qu&#xED;lez"`. So how do i change it back to `"Lluís Quílez"` in C#?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this outstanding [article](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which might help you ;)

and an answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c).

Comment: I don't get why I was downvoted on this.. is there something wrong with my answer ? I'm relatively new here, maybe I'm missing something..

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes, it happens from time to time. Sometimes people *misuse* downvotes if they don't agree with an answer. Anyway, good find of the duplicate question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps someone felt your first link to be not useful. This isn't a Unicode issue at all, really.

Comment: Maybe you're right with the Unicode, I just thought clarifying how encodings in web work wouldn't make any harm as an addition to the solution which is just one line of code ;) Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 5):

The string is HTML encoded. Use the `HtmlDecode` method:

```
s = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
```