# prevent conversion of <br/>

Tags: c#, html

I fear this is a dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer.
Pretty sure what that makes me......

I have C# generated HTML (HtmlGenerator), to which I sometimes want to insert a line break
at a certain part of a cell's innertext.

Here is how that comes out:

```
<TD >There are lots of extra &lt; br /&gt; words here </TD>
```

This then displays the `<br/>` as a part of my cell text - not good.

Am I missing an easy way to have the `<br/>` preserved and not converted to &lt, etc...?

thanks

Comment: I think there is missing some words in your text.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to generate this.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to generate the html? AFAIK, "HTMLGenerator" isn't a standard .Net class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want HttpUtility.HtmlDecode. See this [SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should put real newlines (`\n`) into your text to be converted. Then, if the `HtmlGenerator` doesn't convert those to `<br>` afterwards, you can use a standard string replace yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If this table cell fragment is generated programmatically (in C# for example) then [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) could be what you are after.