# Special HTML Characters

Tags: c#, .net, special-characters, html-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I decode html characters in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

I have characters incoming from an HTML, for example:

```
&quot; &#39; &amp; &gt;
```

Exists an native function in C# to convert to your equivalents?
Thanks,advanced.

***EDIT***
I'm writing a console app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @The mask - There's no problem with referencing System.Web.dll in a console app. It will just work w/o any overhead of deployment issue.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Dont' works for me,not have reference for "HttpUtility" in System.Web. I'm using .net 3.5 framework

Comment: @The mask - System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode is available starting with .NET Framework 2, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Simon: continue don't working. "Erro The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context" my code: http://pastebin.com/TXEecV7u

Comment: @The mask - You need to reference the System.Web.dll assembly. The link I gave above gives precisely a working Console App example.

Comment: The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @The mask - "You need to reference the System.Web.dll assembly"

Comment: Referencing an assembly is different from adding a `using` directive. Right click on the project in VS and choose `Add Reference`

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I didn't know how to say it, you maybe saved my day :-)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: works fine,thanks very much.: ) 
@Simon: sorry for any inconvenience, thanks very much. :)

Comment: @The mask - you're welcome :-)