# How do I convert this string to a normal one so it can be put into an HTML document?

Tags: c#, html

How do I convert this string

```
&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;http://win-thgn9fd7gfo:37996/Style Library/UWW/images/logo01.gif&quot; style=&quot;BORDER: 0px solid; &quot;&gt;
```

to

```
<img alt="" src="http://win-thgn9fd7gfo:37996/Style Library/UWW/images/logo01.gif" style="BORDER: 0px solid;">
```

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) for such things...

Comment: @bhavinp - you should consider marking an answer as "answered" by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 3):

See this [MSDN article on HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx).  You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` to convert those back to their original HTML equivalent characters.

```
var html = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://win-thgn9fd7gfo:37996/Style Library/UWW/images/logo01.gif\" style=\"BORDER: 0px solid; \">";

html = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
// html now = "&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;http://win-thgn9fd7gfo:37996/Style Library/UWW/images/logo01.gif&quot; style=&quot;BORDER: 0px solid; &quot;&gt;"

var html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
// html is now back to its original value.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

Stolen from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
[C#] 
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

   class MyNewClass
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         String myString;
         Console.WriteLine("Enter a string having '&' or '\"'  in it: ");
         myString=Console.ReadLine();
         String myEncodedString;
         // Encode the string.
         myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
         Console.WriteLine("HTML Encoded string is "+myEncodedString);
         StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
         // Decode the encoded string.
         HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);
         Console.Write("Decoded string of the above encoded string is "+
                        myWriter.ToString());
      }
   }
```

Comment: Er, what's the answer here? Also, there's no need to post another answer and delete your old one; you can edit answers after they've been posted.

Comment: I didn't notice that the code was c# and the answer was for php, that's why I've delete it.

Comment: But you could have edited your other answer to have this content (though this, admittedly, also does not answer the question without having to dig through it) rather than creating a new answer.

Comment: If you want straight answers go to www.getacoder.com. Users have to dig a little otherwise they'll never learn, if you want to post the correct answer go ahead.

Comment: Your answer is unnecessarily obtuse. Have a look at the other answers to this question, all of which are correct and are not cluttered with extraneous information. The first part of your answer does not even make sense (the part before "stolen from..."), as it does not mention the class in question (`HttpUtility`).

Comment: The first part was posted by error, thanks for pointing that.