# C# Regex.Replace first group

Tags: c#, regex

How can I use the first group in Regex.Replace?
I've tried using `$1` like the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx) said. Also it doesn't matter if I use grouping with `?:` or not...

```
string text = "&lt;font color=&quot;#aa66bb&quot;&gt;farbig&lt;/font&gt;"     

/// this does not work
Regex.Replace(text, "&lt;font color=&quot;#(?:[\\d\\w]{6})&quot;&gt;", "<font color=\"#$1\">");
// => "<font color=\"#$1\">farbig&lt;/font&gt;"

// this works fine though  
Regex.Match(text, "&lt;font color=&quot;#([\\d\\w]{6})&quot;&gt;").Groups[1];
// => aa66bb
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be just that you are using a non-capturing group here?

```
Regex.Replace(this.Text, "&lt;font color=&quot;#(?:[\\d\\w]{6})&quot;&gt;", "<font color=\"#$1\">");
```

it is:

```
(?:[\\d\\w]{6})
```

instead of

```
([\\d\\w]{6})
```

You can use @ btw to escape all the special chars: `@"(?:[\d\w]{6})"`

Also, have you tried

```
"<font color=\"#" + $1 + "\">"
```

Otherwise I don't think c# will know $1 from an ordinary string value

Comment: hmm, looks like my example without `?:` was messed up in some other way.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the question you are asking, but to do what you are attempting in your example, you could use `HtmlDecode` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c) and avoid the whole problem.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using `HTMLEncode` and only Decode specific tags like b, i, u, br, hr and font.