# Encoding issue with Portuguese characters

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am doing a web request for a Portuguese web page. After I get the result, I see the some of the characters are getting converted to hash format.

Example:

```
Source: PRAÇA DOS OMAGUÁS

Result I am getting : PRA&#199;A DOS OMAGU&#193;S
```

I tired set the encoding format to "IBM860" (reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx) for webrequest. But it is still not able to convert.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("PRA&#199;A DOS OMAGU&#193;S");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("PRA&#199;A DOS OMAGU&#193;S")
```

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode which does not require an extra assembly reference as it is available in the System.Net namespace

[How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)