# Equivalent of python decode(string-escape) in c#

Tags: c#, python, macos, encoding, decoding

Say I have this function in python, that takes a string and just returns the decode('string-escape') of it:

```
def myFunc(s):
    return s.decode("string-escape")
```

Is there an equivalent to this in C#? I've tried a few things like encoding the string into UTF-8 and storing it in a byte array, but nothing seems to give me the exact same string that python does.

EDIT:
sample python usage:

```
>>> from base64 import b64encode     #import base64 encode
>>> s = "x\340s5g\272m\273\252\252\344\202\312\352\275\205" #original string
>>> decoded = s.decode("string-escape") 
>>> print decoded    #print decoded string
x?s5g?m?????꽅
>>> print b64encode(decoded)
eOBzNWe6bbuqquSCyuq9hQ==    #base 64 encoded version of the end result
```

So starting with the same string s in C#, how would I be able to get the same base64 encoded version?

If this isn't clear or needs more info please let me know

Comment: Interesting question - it may be worth showing what python outputs for this so that C# only developers have a bit more context.

Comment: `s.decode("string-escape")` should produce a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code.

Comment: You want to un-escape a python string literal with C#?

Comment: I have the same starting string in python and in C#. I have posted the way I got to the correct end result in python, and was wondering how I could get the same end result in C#. I'm not really sure if that's what you were asking

Comment: Base 64 encoding is simple enough in C#, but I don't think there's a built-in encoder that can decode Python's string-escape format.  You'd have to write that part yourself and then use Convert.ToBase64String to get the base64 encoded version.

Comment: Hmm...do you know of any sources that might be helpful regarding how to decode Python's string-escape format? From my searches, all I can find are examples of using escape characters in strings

Answer (score 1):

Looks if these methods helps

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes()

System.Convert.ToBase64String()

Convert.FromBase64String()
```

Or what you may be looking for is

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584148/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-escape-characters-to-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584148/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-escape-characters-to-a-string%20Click)

usually @ symbol before a string is what c# uses.

If you can clarify your questions it will be helpful