# translate special character in strings

Tags: c#, string, replace, newline

I have a program that reads from a xml document. In this xml document some of the attributes contain special characters like "\n", "\t", etc.

Is there an easy way to replace all of these strings with the actual character or do I just have to do it manually for each character like the following example?

Manual example:

```
s.Replace("\\n", "\n").Replace("\\t", "\t")...
```

edit:

I'm looking for some way to treat the string like an escaped string like this(even though I know this doesn't work)

```
s.Replace("\\", "\");
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584148/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-escape-characters-to-a-string

Comment: Please show an example of the XML you're talking about. `\n` is not a special character in XML.

Comment: He could have a value that contains special characters in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex.Unescape().

Official docs here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is pretty neat. Might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just walk the document and build up the new string in one pass.  Saves a lot of duplicate searching and intermediate allocations

```
string ConvertSpecialCharacters(string input) {
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  bool inEscape = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.Length ; i++) {
    if (inEscape) {
     switch (input[i]) {
      case 'n':  
        builder.Append('\t');
        break;
      case 't':
        builder.Append('\n');
        break;
      default:
        builder.Append('\\');
        builder.Append(input[i]);
    }
    else if (input[i] == '\\' && i + 1 < input.Length) {
      inEscape = true;
    }
    else {
      builder.Append(input[i]);
    } 
  }
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: but that would require me to enter all escapable characters as cases. I am looking for a way to not do that. I edited the question to show what I am looking for.