# Interacting with files that have unicode characters in filename / escape sequence issues

Tags: c#, unicode

I am trying to grab a handle to a file that has unicode characters in the filename.

For example, I have a file called `c:\testø.txt`. If I try `new FileInfo("c:\testø.txt")` I get an Illegal characters exception.

Trying again with an escape sequence: `new FileInfo("c:\test\u00f8.txt")` and it works! Yay!

So I've got a method to escape non-ASCII characters:

```
static string EscapeNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        if (c > 127)
        {
            // This character is too big for ASCII
            string encodedValue = "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4");
            sb.Append(encodedValue);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But when I take the output from this method the escape characters seem to be incorrect.

```
EscapeNonAsciiCharacters("c:\testø.txt")  ## => "c:\test\\u00f8.txt"
```

When I pass that output to the `FileInfo` constructor, I get the illegal chars exception again. However, the `\` in `c:\` seems to be unaltered. When I look at how this character is represented within the StringBuilder in the static method, I see: `{c:    est\u00f8.txt}` which leads me to believe that the first backslash is being escaped differently.

How can I properly append the characters escaped by the loop in `EscapeNonAsciiCharacters` so I don't get the double escape character in my output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more escaped in those strings than you probably intend.
Note that `\` needs to be escaped when in a string, because it is itself the escape character and `\t` means tab.

Windows, using NTFS, is fully unicode-capable, so the original error is most likely due to you not escaping the `\` character.

I wrote a toy application to deal with the file named ʚ.txt, and the constructor has no problem with that or any other unicode characters.

So, instead of writing `new FileInfo("c:\testø.txt")`, You need to write `new FileInfo("c:\\testø.txt")` or `new FileInfo(@"c:\testø.txt")`.

Your escape function is entirely unnecessary in the context of C# in general and NTFS (or, really, most modern file systems).  External libraries may, themselves, have incompatibilities with unicode, but that will need to be dealt with separately.

Comment: Or `new FileInfo(@"C:\testø.txt");`

Comment: Thank you, had a feeling I was barking up the wrong tree. I still need to escape things to pass them to the API I'm interacting with, but that's a different issue. Cheers.

Comment: For future readers, I added a clarification based on your comment.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding escaped characters.

In this C# code, it is the compiler that converts the `\u00f8` to the correct unicode character:

```
new FileInfo("c:\test\u00f8.txt") // (the "\t" is actually causing an error here)
```

What you are doing here is just setting `encodedValue` to the string `"\u00f8"`, and there is nothing ever converting the escaped string to the converted string:

```
string encodedValue = "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4");
```

If you want to convert the escaped string, then you need to do something like this:

[How to convert a string containing escape characters to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584148/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-escape-characters-to-a-string)