Issue with special characters in file name sent by Invoke-RestMethod (Powershell)
I am using Powershell to send a zipped file to a webservice URL. Obviously there is an issue when sending files that contain special characters like äöü ...
$exportPath="C:\test\"
$fileName=testäöü.csv

$originalFilePath = Join-Path -Path $exportPath -ChildPath $fileName
$zipFileName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($fileName, ".zip")
$zipFilePath = Join-Path -Path $exportPath -ChildPath $zipFileName

Compress-Archive -Path $originalFilePath -DestinationPath $zipFilePath -Update

Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $Credential -Uri $RestRequest -Method PUT -InFile $zipFilePath -ContentType "application/zip"`

Output of $zipFilePath is "C:\test\testäöü.zip"
The zip file is then received by the webservice like this:
testÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼.zip
The received zip file itself and its content are ok, not corrupt, but obviously renamed.
If the filename contains no special characters then there s no issue.
What can I do to send/receive it with the correct filename?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share how did you create testäöü.zip file…

Thank you, @JosefZ. I created the zip-File using the Compress-Archive cmdlet. I am sorry I wasn't aware that this might be relevant...
Compress-Archive -Path $originalFilePath -DestinationPath $zipFilePath -Update

Again. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. Stack Overflow isn't a chat. Add output from Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFilePath  as well.

Powershell is built using Net library.  So a c# solution should also work with PS.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069754/interacting-with-files-that-have-unicode-characters-in-filename-escape-sequenc
