# ampersand in sqldatasource parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In ASP.NET I have SqlDataSource, I pass into that `ProductName` as parameter and get `ProductId` from Select method.

Problem is when i pass `ProductName` containing `'&'` then Select Method returns nothing.

I tried replace `'&'` with `'\&'` like `name=name.Replace("&",@"\&");`
 but nothing changes.

How can I handle that problem?

Comment: & is not a special character in t-sql, have you printed out the values and verified its not something like *&amp;* ?

Comment: You're right about & is not a special character - sql query in Managment Studio worked. So it's not a problem here. Yeah I printed that and it is normal string with single &. But still no results.

Comment: If in your asp.net code you hard-code a valid value `name = "Beer & Pie";` does it work?

Comment: Then the string from the query/form data must be weird, when you looked for &amp; did you do it in the debugger? if you look at it written back in the browser you need to view its source

Comment: I have looked at it assigned to some Label.Text; I'll try do it while debugging (now i have some problems with launching that ;) ). I can only add that i get that value from Gridview like : `row.Cells[1].Text;`

Comment: Hi, @Alex K. I managed to debbug it and there is `name="ProductName1 &amp; new"`  , do you know any solution ?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats a solution!