# How to replace web codes with their equivalent symbols?

Tags: c#, replace, html

This could be a duplicate question, but I have no idea what search terms to look up, so don't be hard on me if it has been asked before (and I'm pretty sure it was).

So I am getting a web page's source code using the `WebClient` class and saving the entire string in the `source` variable:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
var data = client.OpenRead(urlAddress);
var reader = new StreamReader(data);
var source = reader.ReadToEnd();
data.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Now I want to process certain text ranges from the `source` variable, especially user posted messages. Now the problem is that in the web pages source "&" is actually `&amp;`, "'" is `&#8217;` and quotes (") are either `&#8211;`, `&#8220;`, `&#8221;` and who knows what else.

Well, I could replace those codes with the actual symbols using the `Replace` string method, but I would like to know if there is a way to convert all those codes to the actual (expected) symbols. Is there a method that can do that, or maybe a library or some utility class on the Internet?

Comment: The term describing what you are seeing is "HTML encoding": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Now I also learned that this thread could answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k) or [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx).

Comment: And forget about using the ClientProfile.

Comment: Yup, because of System.Web.dll. Thank you, mister Justin!