# C# String compare not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, encoding, string-comparison

I'm having some issues with the string comparison of a string the is received by Request.queryString and a line from a file .resx.

The code receive `Request.queryString` to a variable named `q`, then it goes to a function to compare if a line has `q` value in it:

```
        while ((line = filehtml.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower().ToString()))
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<b>Content found!</b>");
            else
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<b>Content not found!</b>");
        }
```

As it's a search in static files, special characters must be consider and seraching for: `Iberê` for example, isn't returning true because the `.Contains`, `.IndexOf` or `.LastindexOf` is comparing: `iber&ecirc;`, that is coming from `q`, with `iber&#234;` that is coming from the line.

Consider that I already tried to use ResXResourceReader (which can't be found by Visual Studio), ResourceReader and ResourceManager (these I couldn't set a static file by the path to be read).

---

EDIT:

Problem solved. There was a instance of `SpecialChars`, overwriting `q` value with `EntitiesEncode` method

Comment: So what you're saying is that the string "iber&ecirc;" isn't equal to "iber&#234;"? That's correct - I'm surprised that you're surprised...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to convert the data to `byte[]` and compare those.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `ê` character is escaped in both strings. So if you did something like this, it wouldn't work:

```
        string line = "sample iber&ecirc; text";
        string q = "iber&#234;";
        if (line.Contains(q)) {
            // do something
        }
```

You need to unscape the strings. Use `HttpUtility` in the `System.Web` assembly. This will work:

```
        line = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(line);
        q = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(q);
        if (line.Contains(q)) {
            // do something
        }
```

As suggested by @r3bel below, if you're using .net 4 or above you can also use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode`, so you don't need an extra assembly reference.

Comment: as written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c, you can use WebUtility.HtmlDecode in .NET 4.0+ :)

Comment: @r3bel The good thing about that is that you don't need an assembly reference to `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: @caerolus - Thank you for your answer. I tried decode, but `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(q) = iber&ecirc;` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(line) = iber&#234;`.

Comment: @FabianoAraujo then your `q` and `line` must be something different. If yo try this `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("iber&ecirc;");` you get `iberê` as expected. If you do `Console.WriteLine(q)` what does it show in the console?

Comment: @caerolus - I'm not sure where should `Console.WriteLine(q)` show the result, but if I try `Response.Write(q)` it shows me `iber&ecirc;`

Comment: maybe you are just unknowingly escaping back after `HtmlDecode`. Try debugging, en execute this `string test = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("iber&ecirc;");`. Variable `test` should be `iberê`. So if your `q` really is `iber&ecirc;`, doing `string test = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(q);` must work as well. Seriously, it works, there must be something wrong with how you check your string values.

Comment: @caerolus - test in this case returns `iberê`, you are right. I solved my problem checking each char in `q` and converting it to it's entity number, with &# before, so `iberê` turns into `iber&#234` as the line from the file has it. Although it's not the best approach, probably. Thanks for your effort and attention.

Comment: @FabianoAraujo turns into `iber&#234` or `iber&#234;`?