# Parsing HTML character codes in VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, hex, alt

How do I parse html character codes for example: "& #36;" (without the space) using Visual Basic .NET?

Comment: First, do a search for ".net parse html character codes".

Comment: I have, and most results are about something entirely different

Comment: In what way did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c not help?

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe is was simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode([String])
```