# Decode HTML entities

Tags: c#, html-entities

I have a string like `&#70;&#101;&#101;&#108` and I want to decode it to its ascii representation - `feel`.
Is there any library in C# that does it, or I have to do it manually?

Comment: Do you really want ASCII? Or do you want a .NET/C# string (which is UTF-8)?

Comment: @elgonzo UTF-8 will be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the limits of this are, but you can (possibly) try HtmlDecode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx

Comment: It is probably better to use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` than `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`. See [here for explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/122658/2819245).

Comment: @elgonzo .NET strings aren’t UTF-8, they’re UTF-16.

Comment: @Konrad: Ooops, ofcourse UTF-16...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decode the string, use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's a sample [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "&#70;&#101;&#101;&#108;";
    string decoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
    decoded.Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
Feel
```

**Note**: You're missing a semicolon from the string you've presented in the question. Without the final semicolon, the output will be:

```
Fee&#108
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, here's a console sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public static String ReplaceASCIICodesWithUTF(String target)
        {
            Regex codeSequence = new Regex(@"&#[0-9]{1,3};");
            MatchCollection matches = codeSequence.Matches(target);
            StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(target);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                String matchedCodeExpression = match.Value;
                String matchedCode = matchedCodeExpression.Substring(2, matchedCodeExpression.Length - 3);
                Byte resultCode = Byte.Parse(matchedCode);
                resultStringBuilder.Replace(matchedCodeExpression, ((Char)resultCode).ToString());
            }
            return resultStringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String rawData = "&#70;&#101;&#101;&#108;";
            Console.WriteLine(ReplaceASCIICodesWithUTF(rawData));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To decode:

[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

then, for example,

[ASCIIEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`GetBytes/GetString` (getbytes on decoded string, then getstring from those bytes)