# WebClient() downloadstring returns HTML with strange symbols

Tags: c#, html, webclient, downloadstring

I am using

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
c.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var vLogin = c.DownloadString("http://www.www");
```

And it returns an HTML, but it appears 
`&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

These (`&lt;` and `&gt;`) are standard HTML character entities. You can use an HTML decoder to get "normal" character.

See [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c) fore more details.