# Regex, trying to get text within XML tag

Tags: c#, html, xml, regex

I have a tag and I am trying to get the actual text from it.

An example of this tag is: (And all are formatted the same)

```
<description>
&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-field-body-small field-type-text-long field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;The evolution of your League of Legends match history is now live!
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-field-article-media field-type-file field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;
&lt;div id=&quot;file-13180&quot; class=&quot;file file-image file-image-jpeg&quot;&gt;
&lt;img typeof=&quot;foaf:Image&quot; src=&quot;/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/upload/mh_640x360.jpg?itok=z_Nn84Op&quot; width=&quot;480&quot; height=&quot;270&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; title=&quot;&quot; /&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-custom-author field-type-entityreference field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;
&lt;span class=&quot;article_detail&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;posted_by&quot;&gt;By Riot MattEnth&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
</description>
```

I want the text on the first line, which in this example contains (far right of code snippet)

`The evolution of your League of Legends match history is now live!`

Is there a simple way to do this with my following code? Right now it returns that entire string of junk.

```
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(@"http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/rss.xml");
var LoLdescriptions = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
                     select (string)service.Element("description");
ViewBag.descriptions = LoLdescriptions.ToArray();

...moving into View...

@ViewBag.descriptions[0]
```

If this is not hard, is there also a way to the get the last line as well? In this case `By Riot MattEnth`

Thank you!

*XML code for reference*: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/rss.xml

Comment: Might I suggest using an actual XML parser for this? Depending on the language there is probably already quite a few very good ones

Comment: I have looked into this, but I have no idea where I would insert it into my current code. I need to use XDocument to load it, and I only care about the first three items. I have tried tacking random things on, but I usually get compile errors as I have never used a parser before :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c

Comment: You really don't want to do this with regular expressions. I suggest you remove regex from the title and from the tags.

Comment: Content of that `<description>` node is HTML. As result you need to use HTML parser (common suggestion HtmlAgilityPack) to read that section and selsct nodes you like. If you want to stick with regEx - this question is indeed duplicate of all times regex favorite question linked earlier.

Comment: Yea I was able to fix it by taking out my <description> query, then decoding the first three items, and then regex'ing all HTML tags. Only 2 lines of code :) Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which language this is. But it seems to me that you need to read the file first and convert all HTML entities. Than you can pass real XML/HTML to your parser as a string.

Don't use regex. Try to get some XPath-able tree from which you can select the element content (i.e. the text).

Comment: Your concept helped me find a similar solution! I just stuffed the `<description>` tags into an array and then used the following parser. `servicing[i] = Regex.Replace(Server.HtmlDecode(servicing[i]), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);` Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting format! You can use this:

```
(?<=<description>.*[\r\n]*.*?&quot;&gt;).*
```

On [the demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=e470ea03-d65a-4b1c-8b87-3e510565c65a), you'll have to scroll to the right to see the match.

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=<description>.*[\r\n]*.*?&quot;&gt;)` asserts that what precedes the current position is `<description>`, then `.*[\r\n]*` any chars to the end of the line, then new line chars, then any chars up to `&quot;&gt;`
- `.*` matches everything to the end of the line

In C#, you can retrieve the match like this:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=<description>.*[\r\n]*.*?&quot;&gt;).*");
string resultString = myRegex.Match(yourString).Value;
```

Comment: Not sure, probably because I shouldn't be using regex as everyone keeps mentioning haha. Thank you for the reply, I did happen to find a very simple fix as well. I just grabbed the first 3 values that I wanted, decoded them, then parsed out all HTML tags. `var servicing = LoLdescriptions.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                servicing[i] = Regex.Replace(Server.HtmlDecode(servicing[i]), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
            }`