# Parsing XML with &lt; and &gt;

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I'm attempting to strip down some XML and get only the value related to a field, however the XML does not use the less than and greater than signs. I try to substring around the field name (in the below case it is Date) and this works fine.

```
    &lt;my:Date xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-07-27T23:04:34"&gt;2014-08-15&lt;/my:Date&gt;
```

However, I am unable to substring around the less than and greater than. My code is as follows:

```
public string processReportXML(string field, string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            string result = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(field));
            int resultIndex = result.LastIndexOf(field);
            if (resultIndex != -1) result = result.Substring(0, resultIndex);

            result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("&gt;"));
            resultIndex = result.IndexOf("&lt;");
            if (resultIndex != -1) result = result.Substring(0, resultIndex);

            return field + ": " + result.Substring(4) + "\n";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return field + " failed\n";
        }
    }
```

I have tried in a test project and it works fine but I always get the index should be greater than 0 in my actual web service. I have also tried using regex to replace the characters but this also didn't work.

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, "&(?!(amp|apos|quot|lt|gt);)", "hidoesthiswork?");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have HTML-encoded data.

Add this at the beginning of your method for a simple solution:

```
xml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xml);
```

You can also use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` if you're using .NET 4.0+ as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122658/598637)

In the long term, you should really be using an XML parser or something like LINQ-XML to access this data.  Regexes are not an appropriate tool for this sort of structured data.

Comment: Thank you :) I should be able to get the innertext between the tags now, right?

Comment: Yes, you really should consider using LINQ to XML to do that though :)

Comment: Okay, I would add a root node to make it well formed, right? Then loop through the HTML and make each element a new XElement?

Comment: You don't need to loop, you can just transform it into a collection via LINQ-SQL.  Read up on it, it's very cool!