# background url when it contains -?/_%

Tags: css, url, background-image

I have a css code below:

```
  background: url('resimler/las-vegas-1366x7 %-68-wallpaper-4495.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto transparent;
```

That css code above doesn't work.
I mean there is this picture, but neither browser nor css does see that.

I know that is a beginner question..
I wanted to search but I couldn't know what to use as keyword..

Thank you.

Comment: also browser says it is : Bad Request - Invalid URL but the picture is there when I look into the filesystem.. :/ can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the characters have special meaning in URLs and will have to be represented in [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to counter that.

In your example, the `%` should be encoded as `%25`.

```
url('resimler/las-vegas-1366x7 %25-68-wallpaper-4495.jpg')
```

With the quotes, the space shouldn't cause issues, but it could also be encoded as `%20`:

```
url('resimler/las-vegas-1366x7%20%25-68-wallpaper-4495.jpg')
```

---

JavaScript's [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) can be used to help with this.

```
console.log(encodeURI('resimler/las-vegas-1366x7 %-68-wallpaper-4495.jpg'));
// 'resimler/las-vegas-1366x7%20%25-68-wallpaper-4495.jpg'
```

Comment: How can I "decode" a string with ASP.NET C#.?
 I needed to use the initial form of URI. Thank you..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c

I have read it. But HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() didn't work for me..
The URI is still encoded.. Can you help me? Thanks..