# C# string unescape '&#xxx;'

Tags: c#, string

How can I unescape a string that contains &#xxx; ?

Example:

"Quelque petite scratch sur `l&#233;cran`"

"Quelque petite scratch sur `lécran`"

`&#232;` | è

`&#233;` | é

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Comment: Not working with Diacritics

Comment: where the  ' come from in the encoded character? it should be &#232; and &#233; without '

Comment: I place it there because the browser was replacing it to their actual character XD

Comment: @Cedric, i removed the ' from your post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebUtility.HtmlDecode` should do the trick, example

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Quelque petite scratch sur l&#233;cran");

        Console.WriteLine("After HtmlDecode: " + b);

    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/148gYR