# Complete HTML Strip function

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex, winforms

I have an HTML string like this:

```
<p>First Sentence is this.&#160;Second sentence is this.</p>
```

I am able to remove the `<p>` tags from the above string using a `regex` function.

But, how to remove `&#160;` - *encoded characters* from the above string in `winforms`?

I don't want `&#160;` to be present in the output.

Comment: Do you _understand_ the regex you copypasted? It's not going to touch the `&#160;` at all. You'll also want to unencode HTML-encoded entities. How to do that is very well documented. See for example [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `XElement.Parse` to get the node value like this:

```
 var htmlString = "<p>First Sentence is this.&#160;Second sentence is this.</p>";
 var result = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(htmlString).Value;
```

If not all the strings contain valid XML structure, or may have no tags at all, you can add fake tags like this:

```
 var htmlString = "<p>First Sentence is this.&#160;Second sentence is this.</p>";
 var result = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<root>" + htmlString + "</root>").Value;
```

Result:

[image]

You might want to add error handling for this, but this is clearly better than using a regex for this.

**EDIT:**

In case this is still not working, and you want to just handle the entities, you can leverage `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` method to replace HTML entities with literals:

```
var final_result = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
```

Comment: I am using winforms and System.Xml.Linq is not getting populated.

Comment: I think adding a reference to the `System.Xml.Linq.dll` (and perhaps, `System.Xml.dll`) should fix it. Also, try adding `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Xml.Linq;` to the list of using statements.

Comment: I tried now by adding `System.Xml.Linq` dll. I am getting the output as `<p>First Sentence is this.Second sentence is this.</p>` That is, I am getting the `html` tags now.

Comment: Could you show me the complete code you have? Using http://pastebin.com/, e.g. I guess you have `&lt;p&gt;` instead of `<p>`, right? Try `var result = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(htmlString.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&amp;", "&")).Value;`

Comment: Now I am able to get the expected output using your latest code. But, fot the `html strings` that containing class names like `<p class=MsoNormal...`, I am getting the error message as `'MsoNormal' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 10.`

Comment: If I am using `regex` - `@"<(.|\n)*?>";` for those `html string`, I am not getting that error message but atlast(end of the html string) i am getting the encoded characters like `\n&#160;\n`. So, I am thinking to do like first to use `regex` and then to work with `xelement` with that regexed `html string`..Is that correct?..Meanwhile  I am trying this way..

Comment: No..I am not getting correct this way..Now I am getting the error message as `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` when doing `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: Do you mean there are strings that do not contain tags? Then, you should just add fake tags in the start and end. Or, you can try using `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, e.g.: `var rs = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);`. You should add a reference to `System.Web`.

Comment: I tried `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` and I got `\n \n` characters at the end of the string.

Comment: Ok, you can use `.Trim()` to get rid of intial and final whitespace.

Comment: I am trying with `trim()`. Meanwhile I am posting here that `html string` in the next comment since too long.

Comment: `<p class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN:0in 0in 0pt;"><span style="COLOR:#1f497d;"><font size=3 face=Calibri>This is the First Sentence.</font></span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN:0in 0in 0pt;"><span style="COLOR:#1f497d;"><font size=3 face=Calibri></font></span>&#160;</p>
<p class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN:0in 0in 0pt;"><span style="COLOR:#1f497d;"><img src="http://servername:8080/tfs/xxx/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/AttachFileHandler.ashx?FileNameGUID=b3c3cb1a-yyyy-xxxx-9bb8-fc1eb1bc6514&amp;FileName=test.png" width=616><br></span></p>`

Comment: Yes. `Trim` I used and I am getting the expected output. I also checked with two other complex `html strings`. Working fine as expected. Thanks for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Great. I am not against using a regex, esp. in cases like this. Perhaps, you can also try with `HtmlDocument`, too. I will test, and let you know.

Answer (score -3):

Considering the fact the input is a plain string

```
string x = "<p>First Sentence is this.&#160;Second sentence is this.</p>";
x= x.Replace("&#160;"," ");
```

This is way too simple, but will work.