# Render asp.net tags loaded from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, tags, literals

I put Literal control on the page and load ASP.NET body from database which contains some asp.net tags.

It renders them as HTML tag so I see something like "Hello <%= SenderName %>" instead of "Hello Sam"

What is the solution.

- all my tags output are string (to make the issue easier)
- asp-tags and html-tags should load from database, no way to put them on aspx file in design-time, the only change I can do is replacing Literal control with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, and if you are using .Net 4.0 or higher, you can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`.

Gotten from here:
[How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Comment: WebUtility.HtmlDecode doesn't render <% %>  .. It just decodes html  " &gt; " ==>  " < "