# What is the encoding of this string?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, decoding

How can I detect the encoding of this string :

```
    "http://sinapress.ir/resize/directory/&#1605;&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593; &#1593;&#1604;&#1605;&#1740;/1439280705853632083.jpg/263/171"
```

The orginal string is :

```
    "http://sinapress.ir/resize/directory/مجامع علمی/1439280705853632083.jpg/263/171"
```

And how can I convert first string to second string in c#?

Comment: Looks like URL- encoding. There is `Sytem.Net.HttpUtility` class that should have a function for encoding and decoding.

Comment: I was worked with HttpUtility.UrlDecode but not respond in this string but work on another string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

```
var urlToDecode = "http://sinapress.ir/resize/directory/&#1605;&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593; &#1593;&#1604;&#1605;&#1740;/1439280705853632083.jpg/263/171";
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(urlToDecode));
```

Answer (score 1):

its normal html encoding. just use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()