# C# Converting string with accents

Tags: c#

How do i convert an accented string to a normal string.

Example:

```
string name = "Chlo&#233;";    
string newName = "Chloé";
```

thks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx) to decode the & escape character :

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Chlo&#233;") // will produce : Chloé
```

Comment: Or `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` if you are using pre .Net 4.