# Decode HTML string where ampersands are encoded as \\x26

Tags: c#, html

I got a string from html like:

```
var htmlStr = " \\x26lt;span\\x26gt; \\x26lt;/span\\x26gt;";
```

I can't decode it to C# string like:

```
 <span> </span>
```

If I modify the string to

```
var htmlStr = " \x26lt;span\x26gt; \x26lt;/span\x26gt;";
```

It works good. But how can I do it by replacing string or others way?

BTW, I use Encoding.UTF8.

Comment: Given your example, replacing `\\x` with `\x` would work. Why does this not suffice?

Comment: `htmlStr.Replace("\\x","\x")` ?

Comment: @npinti I tried, but not work.

Comment: @dotctor Do you try that?

Comment: .Replace didn't worked ? You did assign it back rigth ? `htmlStr.Replace()` won't work. `htmlStr = htmlStr.Replace()` will.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois Because \x is unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: @dotctor Shouldn't it be htmlStr.Replace("\\\\x","\\x")?

Comment: @dotctor It won't work. "\" is a part of escaped symbol and cannot be replaced this way. `htmlReplace("\\\\x", "\\x")` will find 0 occurences since there are no double slashes in original string.

Comment: @DovydasSopa yeah right :) my bad.

Comment: @DovydasSopa I tried that before, not work, so I post a question there.

Comment: What error do you get then?

Comment: @DovydasSopa No error, but you can reference YeldarKurmangaliyev comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it like this

```
var htmlStr = "\\x26lt;span\\x26gt; \\x26lt;/span\\x26gt;";
// Take out the extra stars
var result = Regex.Replace(htmlStr, @"\*\*([^*]*)\*\*", "$1");   
// Unescape \x values
result = Regex.Replace(htmlStr,
                @"\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})", 
                match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(
                    Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, 
                    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
// Decode html entities
htmlStr = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
```

The Output is

```
<span> </span>
```

Comment: Hi, @MohitShrivastava this work fine, I can solve this problem by REG.
But anyone know the decode problem? Always write reg is not a good solution right?

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here: 
[How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

In short, you can use **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode** or **WebUtility.HtmlDecode**

Comment: I can decode the `\x26lt;` but I cant decode `\\x26lt;`

Comment: Just replace it: htmlStr.Replace("\\\\x","\\x");