# Decode special characters from json data in c#

Tags: c#, json, decode

I am getting data in json format from a url. Everything is working perfect, but one small issue is that in the data that I am getting there are some special characters, for example :

> `Get 50% off on Pizzas between 11am &amp;ndash; 5pm.`

`&amp;ndash;` here means that it is '-', but how can I decode it in c# so that it takes it as '-'.

I have tried using Html.decode method, it is working fine with URLs but not with data.

I cannot replace `&amp;ndash;` with '-' everywhere because this is not a single case, there are other similar characters too.

Comment: There is no Html.Decode do you mean WebUitity or HttpUtility?

Comment: WebUtility/HttpUtility.decode works regardless of what kind of string it is (url of other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/H9rpLe

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Get 50% off on Pizzas between 11am &amp;ndash; 5pm"); 

        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

> Output: Get 50% off on Pizzas between 11am – 5pm

Comment: You are correct it works, but just to let you know your fiddle uses `&ndash;`, not `&amp;ndash` - it will work in both cases though :-)

Comment: dotnetfiddle is broken in this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1TA9GU - my original code was `WriteLine("a &ndash; b");`

Comment: @RB. Weird, I copied paste if from the fiddle, where it showed correctly (with amp)...

Comment: Sounds like Wapac has found the culprit - interesting :)

Comment: Thank you all for this information, The issue is solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c).

> You can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
>
> If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode which does not require an extra assembly reference as it is available in the System.Net namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding it twice as it seems you have it encoded twice. First decoding will convert `&amp;ndash;` to `&ndash;`, then second decoding will make it `–`.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "Get 50% off on Pizzas between 11am &amp;ndash; 5pm.";
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        string d = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
        Console.WriteLine(d);

        string e = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(d);
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```