# HTML: Wrong encoding

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I know that this is a common question but I couldnt find an answer for my problem. I am currently working on a HTML editor. With one button click you can change from the webbrowser view to the textview. If I press the button again the webbrowser will be displayed again with the HTML code. But I can also change the code manually in text mode and if I do that the code will be displayed wrong. For example: If I write something like this:

> Ö Ä Ü

and I change something it will show this:

> Ã– Ã„ Ãœ

I already tried this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(mytextbox.Text);
string htmlcode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

and this:

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

but that didnt work. I hope you can help me.

EDIT:

I have a WPF WebBrowser where I can edit my code with mshtml. If I write something like this:

> Ö Ä U

and I change to the text view with this code:

```
mytextbox.Text = doc.body.outerHTML;
```

the HTML code shown in the textbox:

```
<BODY>Ö Ä Ü</BODY>
```

the textbox is ReadOnly if you want to edit this you need to press another button. If I edit the text and change to the browserview again currently with this code:

```
if (myWebBrowser != null)
{
   myWebBrowser.Dispose();
   browsergrid.Children.Remove(myWebBrowser);
}
if (doc != null)
{
   doc.clear();
}
myWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
browsergrid.Children.Add(myWebBrowser);
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(mytextbox.Text);
doc = myWebBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
doc.designMode = "On";
```

the Browser displays this:

> Ã– Ã„ Ãœ

Comment: Can you post the HTML codes ?

Comment: You definitely, *definitely* should be using that code. You shouldn't be using `Encoding.Default` anywhere. Now, how far have you got in the diagnosis of the problem? How are you showing the HTML?

Comment: That's not how encoding works. You can't get bytes in one encoding and interpret them as UTF8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Comment: `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I already tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode too, I will edit my question

Comment: @nicoh In a question you should always include the desired outcome, what you have already tried and a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by myself. Here the solution if somebody wants to know it:

I changed my default document string from

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

to

```
<html><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'><body></body></html>
```

I changed my TextBox to a RichTextBox because the code would be more clear and I was only showing the body of my HTML code with this:

```
mytextbox.Text = doc.body.outerHTML;
```

and I edited it to see the whole HTML code:

```
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
myRichTextBox.Selection.Text= doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

The code to load the html code back to the browser:

```
string htmlcode = new TextRange(myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlcode);
```

**Thanks for your answers!**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `html` codes for those characters. These codes can be found in [This Link](http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html).

In your case:

> replace Ö with &Ouml ; //remove space before ";"
>
> replace Ä with &Auml ; //remove space before ";"
>
> replace Ü with &Uuml ; //remove space before ";"