# Wrong encoding reading html source

Tags: c#, html, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm getting html source from this url : "http://duhoc.dantri.com.vn/du-hoc/30-hoc-sinh-trung-tuyen-dai-hoc-my-nam-2018-chia-se-bi-kip-thanh-cong-20180418093640358.htm" by :

```
      private static string getPageSource(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UserAgent = "SO/1.0";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                //if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                //{
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                //}
                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
                return data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog("Exception get Page Source, Ex = " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The title of the page on browser display like this: "**30 học sinh trúng tuyển đại học Mỹ năm 2018 chia sẻ “bí kíp” thành công**" but when I get html source from that page by calling method given above the title of the page became "**30 học sinh trúng tuyển đại học Mỹ năm 2018 chia sẻ “b&#237 ; k&#237 ; p” th&#224 ; nh c&#244 ; ng**". To resolve this I've change UTF8 tobe:

```
      Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)
```

and UTF7,UTF32 but nothing is working.So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see no differences in the strings you pasted? The website does state it its UTF-8 at least  content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: it is because stackoverflow did correct the paragraph, it should be "30 học sinh trúng tuyển đại học Mỹ năm 2018 chia sẻ “b&#237 ; k&#237 ; p” th&#224 ; nh c&#244 ; ng"

Comment: From the HTML in the "View source" window: `<h1 class="title">
30 học sinh tr&#250;ng tuyển đại học Mỹ năm 2018 chia sẻ “b&#237; k&#237;p” th&#224;nh c&#244;ng</h1>`. The HTML actually contains these values.

Comment: @john : yes, but how browser display it right? how can I convert that title to be what I see It on browser?

Comment: You need to apply System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on your string to resolve the HTML character entities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Comment: @ john : yes, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode resolve this