# How to display/convert currency symbol in MVC view that is set in the Viewbag as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 project in C# and the controller calls the business layer for some validation which returns a string.  This string if not null will return back to the View in Viewbag and display in a dialog which is plan text.  The validation string contains some message and also an amount with pound sign symbol (£).  When it is displayed in the view, the £ symbol shows as `&#163;`

What do I need to do so £ sign displayed as the currency symbol besides using Html.Raw (since it's not a good practice to put this in Razor view)?

Edit: htmldecode is not the right answer.  I need a way to not encode the string again.  Either Html.Raw or MvcHtmlString.Create works

Comment: If you trust the string values, you can use `Html.Raw` which does not do any html encoding

Comment: BTW, you can send your custom error message via ModelStateDictionary as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decode HTML characters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HttpUtility` to decode within your view:

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Value)
```