# Encoding word using C# && dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I try to decode the word **Mickaël** [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/36UXS8)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Micka&#xEBl") ;
        string s2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Micka&#xEBl") ; 

        Console.WriteLine(s1);
        Console.WriteLine(s2);
    }
}
```

But I get this output :

```
Micka&#xEBl

Micka&#xEBl
```

So I need to know how can I decode this word properly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c

Comment: @Renat sorry but it seems that I tried this !

Comment: Your input is missing the semicolon after the `&#xEB`. Decoding `Micka&#xEB;l` works, see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JrGg5j

Comment: @canton7 thank you :) can you please post plz this as an aswer and explain why we have this `Micka&#xEB;l` and `Micka&#235;l` as possible encoded words for `Mickaël`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Your input is missing a semicolon. It should be `Micka&#xEB;l`.

If you check [the specification](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#question), you can see that there are three ways to encode a character in HTML:

> ```
> &#x20AC;      hexadecimal numeric character reference
> &#8364;       decimal numeric character reference
> &euro;        named character reference
> ```

All of them start with a `&` and end with a `;`.

`ë` can be encoded either as a named character reference (`&euml;`), or using its numeric character reference 235, encoded as either decimal (`&#235;`) or hexadecimal (`&#xEB;`).

Your input uses the hexadecimal encoding, but misses the final `;`. If you add it back in, your code works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7PPLu4

<sub>(@OwenPauling identified the problem with the input first. I was asked to post an answer expanding on the different ways to encode the `ë` in the comments)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Your input is incorrect. If you `HtmlEncode` `Mickaël` you end up with `Micka&#235;l`.

```
string s1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Micka&#235;l") ;
Console.WriteLine(s1);
```

Outputs `Mickaël`

Comment: Especially note the semicolon ;

Comment: @Owen I found this word in an email body , then I check the decoded value using this site https://codebeautify.org/html-decode-string